# What's wrong with IF ELSIF?

Tags: oracle

```
    DECLARE DBName VARCHAR(100); ApplicationURL VARCHAR(100);

BEGIN
select NAME into DBName FROM v$database;  

  IF DBName = 'WAMDEV' THEN ApplicationURL := 'http://srpwam10:9080/maximo';
      ELSIF  DBName ='WAMDEVPJ' THEN ApplicationURL := 'http://srpwam10:9080/maximo';
      ELSIF  DBName = 'WAMTST' THEN ApplicationURL := 'http://wamtest/maximo'
      ELSIF  DBName = 'WAMTSTPJ' THEN ApplicationURL := 'http://wamtest/maximo'
      ELSIF  DBName = 'WAMQA' THEN ApplicationURL := 'http://wamqa/maximo'
      ELSIF  DBName = 'WAMQAPJ'  THEN ApplicationURL := 'http://wamqa/maximo'
      ELSE  DBName = 'WAMP' THEN ApplicationURL := 'http://wam/maximo'
    END IF ;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ApplicationURL)
    END
```

It gives me error:
ORA-06550: line 9, column 7:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ELSIF" when expecting one of the following:

- & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
  like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset

  6550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
        *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

Comment: `;` terminates statements, meaning your `if` terminates after the first "then", leaving `elsif` a naked/illegal usage.

Comment: @MarcB - not quite in PL/SQL; it's complaining about the `ELSIF` on line 9 because there *isn't* a semicolon at the end of line 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added the semi colons you were missing

```
DECLARE
  DBNAME         VARCHAR(100);
  APPLICATIONURL VARCHAR(100);

BEGIN
  SELECT NAME INTO DBNAME FROM V$DATABASE;

  IF DBNAME = 'WAMDEV' THEN
    APPLICATIONURL := 'http://srpwam10:9080/maximo';
  ELSIF DBNAME = 'WAMDEVPJ' THEN
    APPLICATIONURL := 'http://srpwam10:9080/maximo';
  ELSIF DBNAME = 'WAMTST' THEN
    APPLICATIONURL := 'http://wamtest/maximo';
  ELSIF DBNAME = 'WAMTSTPJ' THEN
    APPLICATIONURL := 'http://wamtest/maximo';
  ELSIF DBNAME = 'WAMQA' THEN
    APPLICATIONURL := 'http://wamqa/maximo';
  ELSIF DBNAME = 'WAMQAPJ' THEN
    APPLICATIONURL := 'http://wamqa/maximo';
  ELSE
    DBNAME := 'WAMP';
    APPLICATIONURL := 'http://wam/maximo';
  END IF;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(APPLICATIONURL);
END;
```

A CASE statement could also be used and in some eyes is a cleaner look.

Comment: Now I'm not sure if it was supposed to be an `ELSIF` rather than an `ELSE`... maybe that edit wasn't what the OP wanted, but it was invalid before either way *8-)

Comment: I added the missing semi colons, but still error: Error report:
ORA-06550: line 12, column 20:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

Comment: @KyleGu please show the revised script that you got that error from.  Are you clear on the different between equivalence with = and assignment with :=?

Comment: @kevinsky Thank you very much. I still forgot one semi colon after ELSE.